# flexbox with vue js not working

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this simple code? Just starting to explore flexbox. It works well on a normal html but once I vuejs-ed it, the footer stays on the top of the screen as if there isn't flex css.

Thank you.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>THIS IS MY CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This is the footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px; 
/* added as per LGSon's suggestion */
height: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you also give `#app` a height, `height: 100%`, it should work fine

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I added that but still no luck. :(

Comment: And if you give `#app` `flex-grow: 1`?

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Also do note, `display: flex` on the `body` will only apply to its child, which I assume is the `#app`, and if so, the `#app` need `flex-grow: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column`

Comment: oh wow that is magical! Thank you LGSon. Life is great again.

Comment: I added an answer with a simpler CSS to accomplish that. If it solves it, please consider accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that to work, using standard HTML, it should be like this, where the `html`/`body`/`#app` has `height: 100%`, and you set `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the `#app`.

This way the `flex: 1 0 auto` on the `wrapper` will work properly and make it take the remaining available space.

```css
html, body, #app {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>THIS IS MY CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This is the footer
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's much better. I'm using that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I did my vue.js 2 template like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <div v-for="collection in collections">       
         <a v-bind:href="collection.pageurl">  
           <h1>{{ collection.title }}</h1>
           <h2>{{ collection.author }}</h2>               
        </a>   
        </div>
   <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

The CSS like this:

```
#app {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
}

#app div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 185px;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px silver;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```